# Why is 'detail' property of MouseEvent in IE11 always 0 for DOM Level 0 event?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

Is it an IE bug?
It works fine in Chrome & Firefox.

Basically, I have a DOM Level 0 onClick event on a button and the issue arises when I double click the button.. the event handler I associated with onClick is fired twice, which I don't want.

Any clue?

Comment: But... you are clicking twice, why would it not fire twice? ;)

Comment: agree but I want to prevent a double click on a Save button for instance.. my concern is, why the 'detail' property not incremented with each click I do?

Comment: `this.disabled = true;` - now you can't double-click.

Comment: thanks Niet, but I will not be able to click it again then (as it will get disabled after the first click) - I am not able to set disabled back to false in my case.
Typically, I need the button to remain enabled but just prevent double click. I am using dojo framework and have overwritten the __onClick event in _ButtonMixin such that it does not run the .click(e) function if e.detail>1... unfortunately, standard UIEvents in IE do not set this 'detail' value.. :(